# call again a api when id is passed in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have this callback funtion inside useeffect  i want to pass differnt  `props.id`  from parent js to this file so i get differnt datas the problem is  `const res = await axios.get("messages/get-all-messages/?receiver=" + props.id, config );` does not get recalled when i pass a new `props.id`  from parent.js how can i call again this api when i pass a new `props.id`

```
 function chat(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    };
    const data = { receiver: props.id, message: inputField };
    axios
      .post("messages/send-message/", data, config)
      .then((res) => {
        getData();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

```
  const getData = useCallback(async () => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    };
    const res = await axios.get(
      "messages/get-all-messages/?receiver=" + props.id,
      config
    );
undefined which will crash.
    if (res.status === 200) {
      if (mountedRef.current) {
      
        setdata(res.data.);
        
      }
    }
  }, []);
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (mountedRef.current) {
      getData();
    }
    return function cleanup() {
      mountedRef.current = false;
    };
  }, [getData]);
```

Comment: Have you tried adding props.id  to the dependency list of getData which you've wrapped with useCallback ? useEffect is triggered when getData changes, and getData changes  when props.id changes. That's my syllogism here. My point here is that your getData function doesn't have any reason to be recreated.

Comment: @emre-ozgun i dont know how to do that can u hlp with a example sir

Answer (score 0):

```js
useCallback(fn, deps)
```

`useCallback` will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed. Therefore you should have been added `props.id` as dependencies to useCallback hooks

```js
const getData = useCallback(async () => {
   // do something
}, [props.id])
```

Comment: fn, deps what are those i get error that are not defined

Comment: @jisaks **fn** is an inline callback pass in useCallback, **deps** is the dependencies. Once one among of the dependencies change It will fire the callback function

Comment: what should i pass here?

Comment: @jisaks pass `props.id` to dependencies of **useCallback** It will fire API call as `props.id` changes

Comment: useCallback(getData, props.id);  did u mean like this?

Comment: I've given the sample code in my answer

Comment: i dont under stand what to pass in my code at the place of  fn and deps pls help sir

Comment: @jisaks within box bracket of `useCallback` you pass `props.id` as dependencies useCallback(async () => {}, [props.id])

Answer (score 0):

You can add props.id to the useEffect call, anything you pass as the an argument in the array will ensure that useEffect is called. Therefore anytime props.id updates the logic in the useEffect will execute.

"React compares the current value of dependency and the value on previous render. If they are not the same, effect is invoked."

Helpful Source:https://dev.to/nibble/what-is-useeffect-hook-and-how-do-you-use-it-1p9c

```
useEffect(() => {
if (mountedRef.current) {
  getData();
}
return function cleanup() {
  mountedRef.current = false;
};
  }, [getData, props.id]);
```